# How to clean up memory when custom init fails

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, initialization

When my custom initializer fails, I am supposed to return nil.  What is the convention for cleaning up any memory I've allocated in my initializer, that I was expecting would be cleaned up in dealloc?

Here is a contrived example:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        instanceVar1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"blah"];
        if (bad_thing_oh_noes) {
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [instanceVar1 release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

A more realistic circumstance where I can't efficiently check every error condition before I do allocations would be deserializing a complex object containing arrays and the like.

Anyway, do I clean up the allocated memory before returning nil, do I send a dealloc message to self before returning nil, or is all of this managed for me magically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an error occurs during an initializer, you should call `release` on `self` and return `nil`.

```
if (bad_thing_oh_noes) {
    [self release];
    return nil;
}
```

Also, you must make sure that it is safe to call `dealloc` on a partially initialized object.

You should call `release` only at the point of failure. If you get `nil` back from the superclass’s initializer, you should not call `release`.

Normally, you should  not throw an exception upon initialization failure.

An example from [Handling Initialization Failure](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13):

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)aURL error:(NSError **)errorPtr {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:aURL
                                       options:NSUncachedRead error:errorPtr];

        if (data == nil) {
            // In this case the error object is created in the NSData initializer
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }
        // implementation continues...
```

Comment: Silly me, I thought I read through that documentation but I missed the part that answered my question!  Thanks for clearing this up for me. :-)